# How to filter SSL Wrong Host when use CIO engine

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

When I try to use the CIO engine to post data to a website with incorrect HTTPS certificates, I can still successfully get results. Is there any method to enable certificate host name verification for the CIO engine?

Ktor bom version: 2.3.3

for test can post data to: https://wrong.host.badssl.com/

```
HttpClient(CIO) {
}
```

Comment: This is a bug, so I've created an issue in the bug tracker. As a workaround, please use another engine.

Comment: Thanks for help @Aleksei, Can we have the URL to tracking this bug.

Comment: It's https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-6229, but you can't open it because it's marked as a security problem.

Comment: Thanks very much, please let us know when you have fix this :)